# Can Golden Loot Boxes contain duplicates?

Tags: overwatch

While reading online, I saw an [interesting claim](http://deals.kinja.com/1796293595) about Overwatch's golden loot boxes.

> **PSA: The legendary is guaranteed to not be a duplicate.**

While I did not receive any duplicate items when I opened my golden loot box, I can't say whether or not it was by chance.

I've seen a [few forum posters](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20756805887) saying they've received duplicate Oni Genji and Officer D.Va skins, but this could just be a bug considering the skins were only added to regular loot boxes [a few days ago](https://dotesports.com/overwatch/officer-dva-oni-genji-overwatch-skins-15399).

**Aside from the Oni Genji and Officer D.Va skins, are Golden Loot Box rewards guaranteed to be unique, non-duplicate items?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Blizzard Support has come out and stated duplicate items from Golden Loot Boxes is *NOT* intentional, and that they will be compensating players who received duplicates with a second Golden Loot Box.**

[*From the Blizzard Forums:*](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20757445811)

> Greetings,
>
> **You recently received a duplicate item in your golden loot box. We
>   apologize for the mistake, and you'll be receiving an additional
>   golden loot box soon.**
>
> Thank you for your patience!
>
> Regards,
>
> Blizzard Support
>   https://battle.net/support

Comment: I imagine if you had played often enough/spent the money and already had all legendary skins you'd still get a duplicate, yes?  Are you then just guaranteed the legendary duplicate cash?

Comment: @PawnInGameOfLife I suspect that if you own every single legendary in the game (quite a feat, even for hardcore players), you'll just get the legendary credit reward (500 credits), which doesn't count as duplicate of anything.